# Filter with Jpcap

Tags: java, traffic, jpcap

I need to filter Telnet packets using Jpcap.. how can I do it? I've tried with:

```
captor.setFilter("telnet", true);
```

but it does not work...

Answer (score 1):

By calling your captor instance [`captor.loopPacket(-1,handler)`] with a handler like this :

```
public class TelnetReceiver implements PacketReceiver
{
    public void receivePacket(Packet p) 
    {
        if (p instanceof TCPPacket) { //Filter TCP only
            TCPPacket tcp = (TCPPacket) p;

            if(tcp.dst_port == 23 || tcp.src_port == 23)) {
                //Do something with tcp.data or other layer fields
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can filter telnet port (23):

```
captor.setFilter("port 23", true);
```